# Force 2 columns from a table to match 2 columns in another table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Newbie to Microsoft Access here - so it may be trivial.

I have 3 tables:

- Suppliers
- Orders
- Invoices

The flow work that I would want to implement is first to set my suppliers, then add orders and set the supplier for each order, and when I receive an invoice add the invoice and in the order link it to the invoice.

Right now I have the following relationships:

[Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqFtF.png)

All relationships were made by the lookup wizard.

When setting the invoices (Factura) I add the supplier (Proveedor) using a drop down menu.

Then when setting the order (Albaran) first I add the supplier using a drop down menu, and then I select the invoice.

The problem that I'm trying to solve right now is how to make the drop down menu for selecting an invoice for the order only show invoices with the same supplier as the order.

I tried to add a relation ship between supplier in both orders and invoices tables but when I force data integrity it says "No unique index found"

I can't have the order directly in the invoice table because the same invoice can have multiple orders (since I get an invoice per month and I do multiple orders per month).

Comment: It seems you need inner join.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the invoice dropdown dependent of the supplier dropdown. You do this by defining the source of the invoice dropdown where you add as criteria for the supplier the supplier dropdown in your form.

Example:

```
SELECT Factura FROM [Facturas Recibidas] WHERE Proveedor=Forms!mySupplierDropdown;
```

Please chose the correct dropdown name.
For the supplier dropdown you create an AfterUpdate event where you write

```
Me!myOrderDropdown.Requery
```

Again: chose the correct name of the order dropdown.

Additional advise: avoid space-characters in table or field names. This will always lead to problems because you always have to put them into square brackets that Access handle them as one object. Use an underscore character instead, which keeps it readable.

Comment: When I tried to use WHERE [Facturas Recibidas].Proveedor = Albaranes.Proveedor it would prompt me to type a Proveedor in. I didn't know how to adapt "Forms!mySupplierDropdown" into my table.

Comment: You set the SQL-Statement as data source of your invoice dropdown.

Comment: Uhm, so I realized doing it directly in the table is bad practice. I'm now trying to do it in the form. Adding Where [Facturas Recibidas].Proveedor = Form!Proveedor works, but I have to close the form and open it up again. I understand that's what the AfterUpdate thing is for, but when I add Me!Proveedor.Requery in the after update of the Proveedor combobox and I change the Proveedor in the form it gives me an error because "Microsoft Access cannot find the object 'Me!Proveedor'"

Comment: The combobox has an own record source. This can be the name of a table, a query or a SQL statement. You have to enter above mentioned SQL statement as record source of the dependent combobox. The record source of the form will stay untouched.

Answer (score 0):

The solution required an Inner Join

To implement the `Inner Join` I went into the orders table Design View, selected the invoice field and in the bottom of the screen I had 2 tabs. Selected Lookup and changed the Row Source from:

```
SELECT [Facturas Recibidas].Factura FROM [Facturas Recibidas] ORDER BY [Facturas Recibidas].Factura ;
```

to

```
SELECT [Facturas Recibidas].Factura FROM [Facturas Recibidas] INNER JOIN Albaranes ON [Facturas Recibidas].Proveedor = Albaranes.Proveedor ORDER BY [Facturas Recibidas].Factura ;
```

**tldr**: had to add a `INNER JOIN` for supplier in both tables in between `SELECT FROM` and `ORDER BY`.